# Jenkins credential-id scope

Tags: jenkins

A credential-id with global scope is available to all jobs in Jenkins. Is it possible to restrict a particular credential-id only for a specific job? Otherwise each user that create a job have access to all global credential-id in jenkins?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the[Credentials Plugin User Guide](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc) ? Or the [Jenkins Credential User Guide](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/). There a large number of very complex restrictions that can be applied. Let's just say, yes you can.

Comment: I read the document but I didn't find how to bind a credential-id to a particular job ( my initial question)